# What is the python function equivalent of Matlab 'lscov'?

Tags: python, linear-regression, linear-algebra, statsmodels

Salutations,
I'm looking for a python function that is equivalent to the 'lscov' function I use in Matlab.
I have 3 arrays:
A(143,12)
b(143,1)
w(143,1)

In matlab I do: [x,stdx]=lscov(A,b,w)

In python, I tried the following methods:

Method 1:

```
import numpy as np
w=np.sqrt(np.diag(w)) 
Aw=A*np.sqrt(w)
bw=b*np.sqrt(w)
x, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(Aw, bw, rcond=0)
```

Metod 2:

```
import numpy as np
w=np.sqrt(np.diag(w))
w=np.squeeze(w)
Aw=np.dot(w,A)
bw=np.dot(b,w)      
x,res,rank,s=np.linalg.lstsq(Aw, bw, rcond=-1)
```

Method 3:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
x=sm.WLS(b,A,weights=w).fit()
x.params
```

None of them return to me the same graphic value as X.
In particular, x should be a matrix (12.1) of Nan.
With some of these methods I get this matrix, but by graphic the result I get the equivalent of 'lscov(A, b)'.
It is as if it did not take into consideration the matrix of weights w..
Can anyone understand how to fix the code?

Comment: Is your A matrix singular? I don't see why those methods should not agree in well defined cases. You might have to provide a full example with some numbers. (minor issue statsmodels WLS should be 1-dim)

Comment: your sentence "In particular, x should be a matrix (12.1) of Nan." Are they really supposed to be NaN?

Comment: Yes, it should be a matrix of NaN (12,1), as I checked on Matlab (where everything works correctly) and the result is there. In python, although I get a matrix of that type, from a graphical point of view I don't get the same result.
If, however, in the lscov function I eliminate the matrix w, then the graphs coincide, so I hypothesized to be a problem related to the matrix w. Checking the values, they are the same in both matlab and python, so I think it's a function problem used to compute linear regression.

Comment: @Josef I did a practical test.
In matlab I defined:

A=[[1,2,3,10];[4,5,6,11];[7,8,9,12]];
b=[1;2;3];
w=[1,1,1];
x=lscov(A,b,w);
result: x=[0.31;0;0;0.07]

In python, I tried multiple methods:

import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm

x,res,rank,s=np.linalg.lstsq(A,b,w)
x=sm.WLS(b,A,w).fit()
x=sm.OLS(b,A,w).fit()
x=LinearRegression().fit(A,b,sample_weight=w)

same result: x=[0.10714286 0.10714286 0.10714286 0.03571429]

No methods gave me the same result as 'lscov'

Comment: you have fewer observations  than parameters (columns of A). The parameter estimates is indeterminate and depends on how rank reduced design A matrices are handled. WLS and sklearn use SVD, while (based on the docs) matlab sets some params to zero.

Comment: So how can i resolve the problem?

Comment: There is no obvious solution, except directly dropping variables to have full column rank A matrix.  statsmodels and sklearn do not replicate whatever method matlab is using to decide for which variables the coefficients are set to zero. If there is no unique solution, then the algorithmic details choose one of those (or raise an exception).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like lscov returns the OLS solution for linear regression. Sklearn's [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) should be able to do the same things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I installed the LinearRegression from sklearn.linear_model module, and wrote:
x, stdx=LinearRegression().fit(A,b,sample_weight=w)

But I got: TypeError: Singleton array array(154) cannot be considered a valid collection.

Did I make a mistake in setting the inputs of the LinearRegression function?